# I cannot display some hidden or dirty items in a library

Tags: document-library, permissions, drop-off-library

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have a drop box library. I cannot see them after I uploaded some items by using a third party code. For example, I have uploaded 5 items. I can see there are 361 items listing in there if I select 'View all site content". but I cannot see nothing if I go to the library. My question are, is there any way I can find out why it show 361 items there? for example, by using power shell? or go to database to query them directly? is it a permission issue. I have tried using the powershell with out success.

Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can have multiple causes

- item level security. Certain items have specific permissions and you do not have the correct permissions to view them
- document is created but is never checked in. Technically no 'version' of the document has been created and the document is only visible to the creator of the file.

Comment: thanks. do you think it going to be working if i update those values in AllUserData table? I update them, it seem not working.:

this is the sql 
 update [WSS_Content].[dbo].[AllUserData]
set tp_Level = 1,nvarchar15 = 'No', tp_CheckoutUserId = NULL, nvarchar1 ='corp\aaa', nvarchar2='corp\aaa', tp_Version = 3
where (tp_ID = 9 OR tp_ID= 10 or tp_ID= 269 or tp_ID= 954) AND tp_ListId = '2a279021-7ddf-480e-a7ad-0040998f70c3'

Comment: @Wout, Thank you  Wout, the reason with my is the exact as you described as the   second point.